# How to add escaping character "\"?

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON string with double-quotes. I need to send the string further to another application. In order for another application to read it, I need to escape double-quotes. for this, I tried to use the `Replace()` method but in the console it any way prints the string without the backslash character. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jobObj = new Source
            {
                url = "http://localhost",
                name = "YourName",
                age = 54,
                username = "Admin",
                password = "Password",              
                
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jobObj);
            string jsonstring = json.Replace(@"\""", @"""");

            Console.WriteLine(jsonstring);
            Console.ReadKey();


        }

        public class Source
        {           
            public string url { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int age { get; set; }
            public string username { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you escape the double quotes, it's no longer JSON.

Comment: Think about it more clearly. What is the text that appears in the original, that should be replaced? What is the text you should replace it *with*? Therefore, what order do the arguments to `.Replace` go in? (If this doesn't make sense, check the documentation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to switch the `json.Replace(@"\""", @"""")` > `json.Replace(@"""", @"\""")`

Answer (score 1):

[Have a look at what the @ sign does to strings in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim). For a regular string, you can escape a quote (") with `\"`. However with verbatim strings (i.e. strings that start with an @ symbol), quotes are escaped using double quotes ("").

Note that JSON supports single quote strings, so it may be more readable for you to write `"''"`.

So if you wanted to write a string with two quotes, you can either write it as

```
string standardString = "\"\""; // or
string verbatimString = @""""""; // or
string singleQuotesString = "''";
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv3/v7Q4My9dIbiyuCQ115qLq6A0KSczWSE5J7G4WCGgKD@9KDGXq5qLEypeXJJYAqTK8jNTFHwTM/M0NLk4gbKczvl5xfk5qXrhRZklqT6ZeakaDkpgoGmNVVYpBghxSqqrg6VquWr//wcA).